# Default configuration for ngStorage

Tags: angularjs, local-storage, ng-storage

I would like to use `$localStorage` for **ngStorage** through out my application. Is there any way to configure it in ***app.config*** so that I don't need to repeat `$scope.$storage = $localStorage;` code in every controller/service where I needed.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.run` on your module and set `$localstorage.$default` there so it will be initialized when your app runs.